# Get associations when doing Get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I am working on ruby on rails as my API with mongoid. Suppose I have 2 models:

```
class Human
  field: salary, type: Integer
  has_many: dogs
end

class Dog
  field: name, type: String
  belongs_to: human
end
```

I want to get all dogs that human has when I query all humans, how do I do this?

I know embedded documents can do this, but then I cannot find dog document easily. That is why I use association rather than embedded document.

Expected output when I query all human:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "salary": 5000,
        "dogs": [
            {
                "_id": "1",
                "name": "dog1",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "salary": 8000,
        "dogs": [
            {
                "_id": "2",
                "name": "dog2",
            },
            {
                "_id": "3",
                "name": "dog3",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance. I am very new on this and sorry if I asked some stupid questions.

Comment: can't you just do `Human.includes(:dogs)`, can you?

Comment: what do you use as api views? jbuilder or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
humans = Human.includes(:dog)
```

humans consists of the required data with each individual containing the dogs they own with details such as their name.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I don't even know there is a includes method to use. I was reading [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and I saw nothing about it.

Comment: You can find info about it http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes